# Spring boot mvc. Passing a null request body

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

Have a restcontroller mapping with a `@RequestBody TypeA` in it.

`TypeA` is resolved correctly, even if I send a `{}` as a body.
The thing I'm trying to achieve is to have the same logic for when the body isn't sent at all (the `@RequestBody` is null).

Code:

```
@PostMapping('/post')
public ResponseEntity processPost(@RequestBody(required=false) Optional<TypeA> body) {
       return service.someAction(body.orElse(new TypeA());
}
```

So far, the only possible solution I see is to set the `required = false`, wrap the type in Optional, and work with the `.orElseGet(...new)`, which works, but doesn't look valid.

Is there a proper way to have this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want, could you add some examples and what exactly you expect ?

Comment: I am trying to achieve the same behavior for both empty and null RequestBody

Comment: But your desired behaviour is unclear, some code would help

Comment: Added a 'how it is at the moment' example

Comment: Ok thanks, `but doesn't look valid.` - Personally, I think that the only thing wrong is treating `{}` and `null` as the same. But if you really need this, I don't see anything wrong with your code

Comment: Thanks, will stick to this approach then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
@PostMapping('/post')
public ResponseEntity processPost(@RequestBody(required=false) TypeA body) {
       return service.someAction(body == null ? new TypeA(): body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
@PostMapping('/post')
    public ResponseEntity processPost(@NotNull(message = "you can add null description") @RequestBody TypeA body) {

    }
```